# Why do I have to import Ordering.Implicits?

Tags: scala

In he code below I get a compilation error unless I import `Ordering.Implicits`. Why is that import necessary? Is there a way around that? Am I doing something completely off-base?

```
Error:(15, 38) value < is not a member of type parameter A
      case (ah :: as, bh :: _) if ah < bh => findOverlap(c, as, b)
```

```scala
  private def foo[A : Ordering](c: mutable.Set[A], a: Seq[A], b: Seq[A]): mutable.Set[A] =
    (a, b) match {
      case (ah :: _, bh :: _) if ah == bh => c + ah
      case (ah :: as, bh :: _) if ah < bh => foo(c, as, b)
      case (_, _ :: bs) => foo(c, a, bs)
    }
```

Comment: I asked the same question back in February: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/why-are-extra-imports-necessary-for-numeric-ordering-operators/4073 But no, you aren't doing anything off-base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<` method comes from an inner class `Ops` of the `Ordering` trait. There's an implicit conversion inside `Ordering` that provides it, but just having an implicit instance of `Ordering` isn't enough for that to be in scope. You can import it explicitly:

```
  val ordering = implicitly[Ordering[A]]
  import ordering.mkOrderingOps
```

...or you can import `Ordering.Implicits`, which contains a few utility methods for handling `Ordering`. One of them is an implicit conversion which [provides an `Ops` instance whenever you have an `Ordering` in scope](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2c6140f6af09dbd7c05246f047f6b60654b38040/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L302).

Comment: Why is it in scope by default wen you "1 < 3"?

Comment: Because that uses a `<` coming from the `Int` class instead of the one provided by `Ordering` - see https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Int.scala#L143-L155

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you need to import `Ordering.Implicits` is usage of boolean operations like `<`, `>` and so on.

By importing it, you tell compiler to use `scala.math.Ordering.Ops`

```
  class Ops(lhs: T) {
    def <(rhs: T) = lt(lhs, rhs)
    def <=(rhs: T) = lteq(lhs, rhs)
    def >(rhs: T) = gt(lhs, rhs)
    def >=(rhs: T) = gteq(lhs, rhs)
    def equiv(rhs: T) = Ordering.this.equiv(lhs, rhs)
    def max(rhs: T): T = Ordering.this.max(lhs, rhs)
    def min(rhs: T): T = Ordering.this.min(lhs, rhs)
  }
```

allowing you to call `<` on type `A`